# WP shortcode for linking image to external URL

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, shortcode

I want to add a shortcode named 'image_code' which should link to an external URL for my portfolio image.

In shortcodes.php I added:

```
add_shortcode('image_code');
function image_code($atts, $content = null) {
    $url = esc_url( $content );
    return "<a href='$url'><image src='$url' /></a>";
}
```

In the wordpress portfolio site I added:

```
[portfolio_item columns="4" image="http://www.nairobigarage.com/wp-    
content/uploads/2014/09/NG_startup_image_movas.png" title="Movas Group" text="Company that enable  
mobile subscribers to access emergency airtime on credit easily and instantly." 
image_code="http://www.movasgroup.com/" ]
```

Everything is fine except the link doesn´t link to the movas website, the link is the www.nairobigarage.com so my home link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The example doesn't match the shortcode definition.

Comment: Where are you using your shortcode "image_code" ?

Comment: My mistake, I am using image_code in the portfolio_item code then: image_code="http://www.movasgroup.com/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced my shortcodes.php with this one http://pastebin.com/3pWhtRTw and added the link parameter in the shortcode, like [portfolio_item link=”http://google.com”]

Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in shortcode.php.

```
<?php
    function image_code( $atts, $content="" ) {
        $url = esc_url( $content );
        return '<a href="'.$url.'"><image src="'.$url.'" /></a>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'portfolio_item', 'image_code' );
?>
```

Also use the below short code in the page where you want to display the same.

```
[portfolio_item]http://www.nairobigarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/NG_startup_image_movas.png[/portfolio_item]
```

Comment: This sadly didn´t work, but I got it to work, but actually don´t know how I did it. Added a 'link' => '' to portfolio_item and now it works.

Comment: Sorry...
Good. Keep it up.